# database structure for recurring inspections based of start date and frequency

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a problem where I need to design a record system for storing building inspections.

An inspection would need to be done on a specified frequency, lets say monthly based off a start date.

I imagine an inspection would need a record in an `inspections` table with an `id`, `startDate` and `frequency`, then each time the inspection is carried out, an entry would be put in an `inspection_record` table with the `id`, `inspectionDate` and other data.

This would be fine if it only needed to be "X timeframe" after the last inspection, but the inspections may not take place on the day they are required, they may be done days before or after which over multiple inspections can create "bracket creep".

Its easy enough to generate a list of dates from the `startDate` based on `frequency`, but how do I make sure an `inspection_record` has been done. As I would need to get a list of all inspections that are overdue or due within a month.

The only way I can think to do it is take the `startDate`, todays date and frequency, find how many times the frequency fits in and round it down to the closest int and up to get the closest before and after inspections, then use that to determine "inspection brackets" and check if an actual inspection happened in those brackets, that seems very messy and slow on a large scale.

Any ideas? or even a term I could use to search for this?

Would it be easier to implement some sort of cron like system? but then, how do I determine that an inspection was actually done around the right time? as just say the inspection is due on the 1st of this month, but does not get done until the 14th, it needs to be seen as the inspection for the this month and next months is still due on the 1st.

Comment: Add a calculatedInspectionDate and an actualInspectionDate column to the InspectionRecord table.  In the example of your last paragraph, the calculatedInspectionDate would be Aug 1, 2021 and the actualInspectionDate would be Aug 14, 2021.  Then you can calculate the deviation of 13 days.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I suppose that may be an option, What would happen if an inspection was missed? I was thinking of something similar with creating the 'next' inspection on first creation and every inspection and just storing the `dueDate` but has the same issue with missed inspections.

Comment: Create a MissedInspection table.

Comment: Perhaps better asked on sister site, https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have another column, `next_scheduled_date`.  When an inspection is performed, update that column to `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`.

With that column, you can discover

```
WHERE next_scheduled_date < CURDATE()  -- task that are overdue
WHERE next_scheduled_date = CURDATE()  -- due today
WHERE next_scheduled_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY -- this week's tasks
```

etc.

Comment: I think I will go with this solution. How would I work out the next date if 1 or more inspections are missed? eg. for the past 2 months no inspections are done, but one was done today, how would I work out when it is next due?

Comment: @mike16889 - Think of what is important about the timing of an inspection.  What's the use of doing a delayed inspection, then doing another one the next day?  So, N days from the last actual inspection.  (Contrast:  mortgage payment or apartment rental payment.)

Comment: Unfortunately with these types of inspections they have to be done on the anniversary of the first one (within a window), bracket creep is not an option, if an inspection is missed or late you are non compliant until the next one, if you stray from the schedule, you will always be non compliant for a period of time every cycle.

Your credit card company does not let you pay your monthly payment 30 days after your last one for example.